# What typeface might this be?

Tags: fonts

Does anybody know which typeface might this be and can it be used with LaTeX via a package?

http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Jacobian

Thank you!

Comment: Looks (mostly) like a variant of Times Roman. The main exception would appear to be the uppercase letter "*J*". The `\partial` symbol also looks like it's drawn from a different font.

Comment: while the linked question as "possible duplicate" is eminently successful at identifying fonts in a pdf file, the page linked from the question is an `html` file created using `css`.  unless the `css` file is available, the mechnism in the suggested duplicate isn't going to help.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was assuming the question was about the math in that site, which is embedded as gif images, which in turn makes the other question relevant again. The HTML font is plain old Times New Roman, as can be found out with the Firefox Addon [fontinfo](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/fontinfo/), which was coincidentally written by none other than [Jonathan Kew](https://tug.org/interviews/kew.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is URW Garamond:

http://tug.ctan.org/info/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.html

It seems to be fairly complete.